# How much does non-unique content (e.g. product specifications) affect SEO in the context of e-commerce?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, ecommerce

Say we have a fairly successful (locally, on its product niche) online store with original content (images, descriptions, specifications). Now, we are given the possibility of working with an additional supplier which supplies products of a different kind. These products are provided with their own content (images, descriptions, etc.) for other re-sellers to use (content which is already present on the supplier's website). It should also be mentioned that these newly supplied products amount to a greater number than the products currently available on the store.

If we choose to indeed import these new products into our online store, how would such a decision affect SEO? More specifically:

- As most of the products are now "copied" (i.e. the content is already present on other websites), will search engines perceive this move in a negative fashion?
- Given that the newly imported products are of a different category (although all products are part of the same broader category; say, initial products are home appliances and newly imported are furniture), will search engines "shift" their perspective of the store towards one that now *mostly sells* furniture?

Answer (score 2):

If one searches for a page with many duplicates,

> apache2 debian default page This is the default welcome page used to
> test the correct operation of the Apache2 server after installation on
> Debian systems.

There is only one site that actually shows that as the page. This is how duplicate or non-unique content is handled by google.

Every other listing is either quotes from the page with other content explaining it; using a graphic for the page; Or has enough other content on the page such that it is no longer that duplicated default page.

If the features are on the box, an image of the box listing features removes the duplicate content ... Get creative. But it is not likely your product page will become a doorway page to your site. The customers will find the product from your site; Not find your site because they searched for the product.

Since you are selling a product, which others are also selling. The more you can tell the visitor as to why they should buy from you the better, in more than one way.

Go heavy on brand marketing, which is unique content on these pages.